# How to set xml:space="preserve" from Flex/Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am working with ActionScript 3 and I need to add a simple tag to one of my XML nodes.
I am trying to add xml:space=preserve tag to one of my text nodes.

```
var tSpan : XML = new XML ( "<tspan xml:space=\"preserve\"></tspan>" );
```

My problem is, the moment I add the tSpan node to my main XML, the tag is automatically converted to something like this:

```
<tspan aaa:space="preserve" xmlns:aaa="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">.....
```

Any idea on how to add xml:... values to an XML node with Actionscript?

Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a namespace definition for `xml:` within your node. It would look like this.

```
var tSpan : XML = new XML ( "<tspan xmlns:xml=\"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace\" xml:space=\"preserve\"></tspan>" );
```

The `xml:space` attribute requires the a namespace definition. See this document for more details. http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace